# Form not posting data to Spring Controller

Tags: java, angularjs, json, spring-mvc

I am really new to Spring and tring to learn through some tutorials on the net. I created a simple Spring MVC Login App using AngularJS as the frontend and using JSON to post data to Spring Controller.

My simple login form:

```
<form id="loginForm" ng-submit="login()" novalidate ng-controller="loginController" align="center">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-10">
                    <label for="username" class="control-label">Username</label>
                    <input class="form-control" ng-model="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-lg-10">
                    <label for="password" class="control-label">Password</label>
                    <input class="form-control" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-25">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

My angular controller:

```
function loginController($scope){
    $scope.login=function(){
        var data=$scope.fields;
        var response = $http.post("rest/dologin",data);
        alert(response);

    };
};
```

My Web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>pages/login.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-core.xml
    </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring-mvc.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

My Spring Controller:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {




@RequestMapping(value = "/dologin", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"Content-type=application/json"})
protected @ResponseBody String validateUser(@RequestBody User user) {

    System.out.println(user.getUsername() + " " + user.getPassword());
    return "Sucess" + " " + user.getUsername();

    }
}
```

My Dispatcher Servlet:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd  
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"     
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.app.web.controllers" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

I tried putting an alert box in the Angularjs controller and it displays but the print statement in my Spring Controller doesn't print. Also, there are no errors displayed.

Update:

I tried posting data to my Spring controller and it gives correct response. So, problem is with the AngularJS Controller. I tried using firebug and see that the login method in angular controller is not called but the script itself is loaded.

Update2:

I changed my AngularJS controller to this and now the controller is getting detected:

```
var loginApp = angular.module('loginApp',[]);
loginApp.controller('loginController', ['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {

  $scope.login = function() {
          var data=$scope.fields;
          var response = $http.post('/test/rest/dologin',data).success(function(data){
            alert(response);
          });
      }
```

This time I get a "Error 400 Bad request" error code in Firebug:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 400 BAD_REQUEST</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 400</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /test/rest/dologin. Reason:
<pre>    BAD_REQUEST</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>                  

<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                
<br/>                                                

</body>
</html>
  };
}]);
```

The server is giving following exception:

```
NotReadableException: Required request body is missing
```

Please suggest what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3):

I think your method is returning a logical view name. Instead of that you should use @ResponseBody annotation just above your validateUser method and then try to return any string because this annotation will directly send the output as response instead of sending it to view resolver as logical view to be resolved
Try this link , in this json post to java using spring mvc is explained good
 http://hmkcode.com/spring-mvc-json-json-to-java

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What you say, does make sense to me. I included these changes in my code. Still the same error though :(

Answer (score 1):

In your ajax call you are sending "data" and in your controller you are expecting username and password how is it possible? @PathVariable is used when you are sending something from the  URI. You are making a POST request so there is no way possible to get data from the URI. USE @ModelAttribute("userForm") User user( This is your POJO object corresponding to your form with username and password)

I'd recommend you to take a look at some examples

Why Does your URL mapping states "rest" when you are not even using a rest controller?

Comment: I may have mixed some tutorials. Can you please suggest a good one if you have any? I tried mapping to rest because this is what I would like to do in the future. Right, now just using a simple spring controller.

Comment: The best would be this: [link] (https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/) The reason I asked about mapping your URL with REST is because it doesn't make any logical sense, Try to make it reasonable and logical. Also, Spring provides a RestController which is a bit Compliant with JAX-RS. Anyway, happy learning.

Comment: I tried changing the spring controller as you mentioned..Still the same :(

Comment: @p19 Try change `@ModelAttribute("userForm") ` to `@ModelAttribute`.